# How to change a negative number to zero in python without using decision structures

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, validation, negative-number

I have a program that determines the number of points you get per day, for 5 days from an event.

source code:

```
total=0

for x in range (5):
    points=int(input('How many points did you get today?'))
    total=total+points

print ('You got {0} points this event'.format(total))
```

My question is how do I get it to make any number below or equal to zero a 0 without using decision statements (if's, case's, i think while or for loop is not allowed either)

Answer (score 174):

Can you use built-in functions? Because this is normally done using:

```
max(0, points)
```

To apply it to the program you gav

```
points=int(input('How many points did you get today?'))
total = total + max(0, points)
```

Comment: since `max(iterable, *iterables, key, default)` can you explain the argument here

Answer (score 26):

```
>>> f=lambda a: (abs(a)+a)/2         
>>> f(a)
0
>>> f(3)
3
>>> f(-3)
0
>>> f(0)
0
```

Answer (score 7):

Since I don't see boolean operators as a restriction, you can use:

```
points * (points>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it via bitbashing, avoiding multiplication:

```
def zerolimit(n: int) -> int:
    """normalize 'n' so that
        n = 0 when n < 0, else
        n = n
        """
    return n & ((n < 0) - 1)
```